# macOS Mojave Bluetooth connection issue

Tags: macos, mojave, bluetooth, mac-mini

I have a problem with the Mac Mini 2018 and its bluetooth.
The problem is that I cannot see my mac via bluetooth with other devices.
Magic KeyBoard only works by wire. Bluetooth turns on and off, but can not create a connection with the keyboard, and also does not see other devices.

Already tried to do a reboot, reset the module, deleting files com.apple.Bluetooth.plist - did not help.

output logs bluetoothd when I turn on bluetooth:

```
2019-07-24 14:30:22.195 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.196 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.218 bluetoothd[1039:58307] Nonconformant HID device with vendorID 4c productID 26c does not specify HIDBootDevice
2019-07-24 14:30:22.373 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.373 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.373 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.384 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.384 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.384 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.384 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false
2019-07-24 14:30:22.384 bluetoothd[1039:58307] [setSystemPreference] syncs returns false

2019-07-24 14:47:23.585 bluetoothd[1214:76246]  manageStateMachine entry:
    clients(0)
    founddevices(0)
    failedNR(0)
    pendingnames(0)
    _currentActivity = 0
```

output of bluetoothd logs when trying to connect a bluetooth device (keyboard):

```
Create connection failed (0x4) for device: 10-94-BB-BC-8A-90
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the disconnected cable to the bluetooth module.
*Fixed*

Comment: Can you please clarify this answer, as I believe I'm experiencing the same issue; are you saying a cable to the physical Bluetooth module had become disconnected somehow? How did you discover and address that? Won't this void your warranty?